# Looping python script in macOS terminal with specific filenames

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm trying to loop a python script through a bunch of files. The python script looks at two types of files each run: a **XX.nii.gz** file and an associated **XX_aparc+aseg.nii.gz** file. The **XX** is a number identifier of the file.

The python script has the following format:
`./pythonscript.sh -s XX -t XX.nii.gz -a XX_aparc+aseg.nii.gz -o output_dir`. The -s flag creates a folder in the output_dir with the specified name (I would like the name to be the number identifier of the file XX). The -t flag looks at the specified XX.nii.gz file. The -a flag looks at the specified XX_aparc+aseg.nii.gz file.

I've tried `for f in *.nii.gz; do ./pythonscript.sh -s XX -t XX.nii.gz -a XX_aparc+aseg.nii.gz -o output_dir; done`. I know that wouldn't work because of how the files are named, but I can't quite figure out how to specify the values that I would like for each of the flags whilst only iterating through the relevant files. I would like the python script to run on only the XX.nii.gz files whilst specifying the associated XX_aparc+aseg.nii.gz file. There are also other types of files and subfolders in the directory related to the execution of the python script that I would not like the python script to look at.

Comment: Your approach basically is possible, but inside your loop, you have to extract that XX value from the filename stored in `$f`. A different approach would be to modify the Python program so that it does the looping by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that this has very little to to with either Python or Terminal, and everything to do with the [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) you are using, which is probably [zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/) if you're on a reasonably modern Mac.

In that case, you could do something like

```
for f in *.nii.gz(:s/.nii.gz//); do
    ./pythonscript.sh -s $f -t ${f}.nii.gz -a ${f}_aparc+aseg.nii.gz -o output_dir
done
```

This magic uses the `:` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to invoke the `s///` [history modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to delete part of the matched filename. (This is also described in the zshexpn(1) manpage that you can read by running `man zshexpn`.)

Comment: I tried your code and it works almost perfectly! The only tiny issue is that the code first runs the XX.nii.gz file through the -t flag but then also tries to run the XX_aparc+aseg.nii.gz file through the -t flag. I tried to resolve this issue by modifying `*.nii.gz(:s/.nii.gz//)` to `*.nii.gz(:s/_aparc+aseg.nii.gz//)`, but that didn't do it. Is there some other magic that can specify excluding specific files? This isn't a huge issue, as the script simply throws up some errors and then moves on to the next .nii.gz file. Regardless, thank you for saving me a lot of time!

Comment: Ah, clumsy of me. The problem, of course, is that `*.nii.gz` matches `XX_aparc+aseg.nii.gz`... The quickest solution I can think of is to match and remove the longest suffix, i.e. change the glob expression to `*_aparc+aseg.nii.gz(:s/_aparc+aseg.nii.gz//)`. (You can probably turn on the [HIST_SUBST_PATTERN option](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Expansion-and-Globbing) and use a pattern in the replacement to avoid having to type the suffix twice.)

Comment: Ah yes! Perfect! That seems to have done the trick. Thank you!